# Updating an existing NetworkLink

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a system set up where a simple NetworkLink is installed in many user systems.

I then periodically (every week or so) update the kml/z file that it links to and users can refresh to see the latest version.

It would have been nice had I made it automatically refresh but when I created it I did not think too hard.

So is there a way of installing a updating process in the already distributed networklink, or can this link work through a second networklink to get the large kml file in a 'mostrecentversion' mode.

It would also be nice to make the links a little more invisible.

The link is currently:
The kml has the usual header and contains this one object

```
<NetworkLink>
  <name>etc</name>
  <Snippet maxLines="0"/>
  <visibility>1</visibility><open>1</open>
  <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
  <flyToView>1</flyToView>
  <Link>
    <href>http://dl.dropbox.com etc TrapLinesData.kmz</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```

But I did not put any refreshModes etc.

Any thoughts on this bootstrapping need will be appreciated as trying to show the less skilled user how to Refresh is becoming a problem.

Bob J.'

Answer (score 1):

By having a [NetworkLink](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink) in your KML makes all Google Earth clients load the latest KML that is referenced each and every time they start up. Google Earth will not store the contents of the NetworkLink (only NetworkLink reference itself) -- that content is fetched each time upon startup.

If you only update your target KML once a week and not every hour then you should not have a problem with the KML as it currently exists in clients. The only clients that won't get the update are those Google Earth clients that stay up and running for weeks at a time which is not that common.

If you want to force a refresh even for a week interval then you could define NetworkLink as the following:

```
<NetworkLink>
  <Link>
    <href>...</href>
    <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
    <refreshInterval>604800</refreshInterval>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```

If your KML is only for a particular region then you may want to define a [Region](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#region) in your NetworkLink and change `<viewRefreshMode>` to *onRegion* so it only loads when that Region is in view. No need to fetch your KML if the region is not in view -- KML best practice. Your KML would then look like this:

```
<NetworkLink>
  <Region>
    ...
  </Region>
  <Link>
    <href>...</href>
    <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
    <refreshInterval>604800</refreshInterval>
    <viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```